# mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string with bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli, parameters, bindparam

i am getting the error when i call the archive.php in browser: 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in...

```
<?php
    $connection = new mysqli('localhost','root','', 'scale');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Error de conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $stmt = $connection->prepare('  SELECT
                                    R.cod_region, P.region, P.comuna, COUNT(DISTINCT(P.id)) AS sitios, COUNT(DISTINCT(A.TEXTO)) AS alarmas
                                    FROM region R, pop P, sitios_pop SP, sitios S
                                    LEFT JOIN log_alarm_2g A ON S.RSITE = A.RSITE AND A.CLASE = "A1"
                                    AND A.INICIO >= "2016-02-14"
                                    WHERE
                                    R.cod_region = ? AND
                                    R.region = P.region AND
                                    S.ESTADO = "OPERATIVO" AND
                                    S.SITIO = SP.cod_sitio AND
                                    SP.id_pop = P.id
                                    GROUP BY
                                    P.region,
                                    P.comuna
                                    ORDER BY
                                    R.cod_region ');

    $stmt->bind_param('i', $cod_region);

    $resultset = mysqli_query($connection, $stmt);
    $records= array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
        $records[] = $r;
    }       
    echo json_encode($records);
?>
```

Comment: seems your database connection in object oriented  and you execute query in procedure oriented, so if you follow just one of then in complete code you did not face this type of errors.

Comment: @rjgodoy, use `$stmt->execute();` instead of `mysqli_query($connection, $stmt);`

Comment: @RohitGoyani already answer below!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using `prepare and bind` statement we use **[execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)** instead of `mysqli_query()`

What you have to do use `execute()` and `get_result()` as

```
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $cod_region);

  // $resultset = mysqli_query($connection, $stmt);
  $stmt->execute();// use execute
  $records= array();

  $result = $stmt->get_result();
   while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc($result))
  {
     $records[] = $data;
  }
```